# How can I ensure that two parameters are comparable?

Tags: python, python-3.8, mypy

I'm implemented an Interval class similar to this simplified version:

```
class Interval:
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        assert left <= right
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def intersect(self, other: Interval) -> Optional[Interval]:
        if other.left < self.left:
            self, other = other, self
        # self starts first

        if self.right < other.left:
            return None

        return Interval(other.left, min(self.right, other.right))
```

I'm now wondering in both cases how I can add good type annotations. My main question is about the constructor: How can I make sure that left and right are comparable? They could be both strings, both numeric, or any arbitrary type which implements `__le__`. Can mypy check that?

Comment: Related: [How can I ensure that arguments have same type without listing the types explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43162832/562769)

Comment: See also: [A Comparable type?](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/59)

Answer (score 1):

Python's type annotations aren't powerful enough to express that.

You can write a [Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) that specifies the presence of comparison methods, but there's no way to specify that objects are comparable *to each other*. Also, mypy doesn't understand `functools.total_ordering`, so you'll get spurious errors for any class that uses it.

(Also, *every* class technically has a full set of 6 comparison methods, due to the details of how `object`'s comparison methods are generated from its C-level `tp_richcompare` slot, but mypy doesn't think so.)

---

The (insufficient) Protocol would look like

```
class Comparable(typing.Protocol):
    def __eq__(self, other): ...
    def __ne__(self, other): ...
    def __lt__(self, other): ...
    def __le__(self, other): ...
    def __gt__(self, other): ...
    def __ge__(self, other): ...
```

Note that I haven't put any annotations on the methods. This is deliberate - "obvious" annotations like `def __eq__(self, other: Comparable) -> bool` are wrong.

Comparison methods are supposed to accept arbitrary other objects and return `NotImplemented` if they don't recognize the other object. That means no bound can be placed on `other` aside from `object`. Additionally, mypy doesn't understand `Union[bool, type(NotImplemented)]`. Also, in some cases, comparisons may return a result other than a `bool` or `NotImplemented` - for example, comparing two NumPy scalars will return a `numpy.bool_` instance that isn't a bool, but mostly works like one.

Comment: How would such a protocol look like?

Comment: @MartinThoma: Answer expanded.